# Build parent pom and run specific integration test in Jenkins through maven?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, integration-testing

Executing `mvn clean install` on my parent pom builds all the sub-modules and runs the related junit tests. It doesn't run the integration tests.

After building and running the junits, I want to run a specific integration test in a particular sub-module.

I am using following command:

```
mvn clean install -DTest=integrationTestName
```

The job fails with `No Test Found` error during build phase.

I also tried using

```
mvn clean install -DTest=integrationTestName -pl=sub-module-name
```

but this only builds my sub-module having integration test.

**Question**: How to run a single integration test of a certain module?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you tried the [`test`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test) option (lower case) of the Maven Surefire Plugin to invoke a specific test, which Surefire couldn't find in the first module of the reactor build and hence fails.

I also suppose integration tests are executed by the [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin). If not, they should, as mentioned by official documentation:

> The Failsafe Plugin is designed to run integration tests while the Surefire Plugin is designed to run unit tests. ... If you use the Surefire Plugin for running tests, then when you have a test failure, the build will stop at the `integration-test` phase and your integration test environment will not have been torn down correctly. .. The Failsafe Plugin will not fail the build during the `integration-test` phase, thus enabling the `post-integration-test` phase to execute.

To make it short: it's safer and much more robust to do so.

Although the plugin configuration entry for the Maven Failsafe Plugin is also [`test`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#test), its corresponding command line option is `it.test`, so you should instead run:

```
mvn clean install -Dit.test=SampleIT
```

Where `SampleIT` is an integration Test (note the standard `IT` suffix, [recognized by default](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) by Failsafe.

The official [Running a Single Test](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/single-test.html) documentation also provides further details on running single integration tests.

---

Also note: the invocation above will work if you don't have other integration tests in other modules of the build, otherwise it will fail not finding it earlier (before hitting the concerned module).

If you are using Surefire to run the concerned integration test (again, you shouldn't) or you have several modules running integration tests, you should then configure a profile in the concerned module which would take care of this specific invocation, something like as following:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>run-single-it-test</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>single.it.test</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <test>${single.it.test}</test>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And then invoke the build as following:

```
mvn clean install -Dsingle.it.test=SampleIT
```

As such, Maven will [activate the profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) based on the existence of a value for the `single.it.test` property and pass it to the `test` property of the Failsafe Plugin (or the Surefire, if it was the case), Failsafe will ignore any other integration test for that execution and other modules would not suffer any impact (ignoring that property).

Answer (score 2):

A_Di-Matteo's answer gets you most of the way there, but you need the following config for maven-surefire-plugin to suppress all the unit tests as well.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>run-single-it-test</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>single.it.test</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                        <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <test>${single.it.test}</test>
                        <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```